# Remove (Or) Empty Duplicate OpenGraph Induced By Unknown Plugin/Theme

Tags: wordpress, facebook-opengraph, jetpack, yoast

I am trying to use Yoast SEO fully. But my theme or some unknown plugins are introducing another opengraph tag section overwriting Yoast's metadata. How do I eliminate the second duplicate set?

1. Here is the list of plugins that are currently installed - *Akismet Anti-Spam, AP Theme Utility Plugin, Featured Image from URL, Jetpack by WordPress.com, Page Builder by SiteOrigin, Proxy Cache Purge, Random Banners, Social Share WordPress Plugin - AccessPress Social Share (Tester), VaultPress, WP Extended Search, WP Responsive Recent Post Slider,Yoast SEO*. The Social Share plugin is to show share buttons underneath each post and I did disable it to yield nothing in change of my metadata.
2. I have added this code my theme's functions.php file - `add_filter( 'jetpack_enable_open_graph', '__return_false' );` which is a strong confirmation that Jetpack's open graph tags are disabled all across the site.
3. Please see the source of this link - https://www.tnilive.com/?p=5372

Here is Yoast's metadata

```
<!-- This site is optimized with the Yoast SEO plugin v11.0 - https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/ -->
<meta name="description" content="Chaganti Pravachanam On Venkateswara Vaibhavam In Nagpur - Latest Devotional Breaking News In Telugu | నాగ్‌పూర్ ప్రవాసులను పరవశింపజేసిన చాగంటి ప్రవచనం"/>
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.tnilive.com/2019/04/29/chaganti-pravachanam-on-venkateswara-vaibhavam-in-nagpur-mesmerizes-audience/" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Chaganti Pravachanam On Venkateswara Vaibhavam In Nagpur" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Chaganti Pravachanam On Venkateswara Vaibhavam In Nagpur">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.tnilive.com/2019/04/29/chaganti-pravachanam-on-venkateswara-vaibhavam-in-nagpur-mesmerizes-audience/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Telugu News International - TNILIVE" />
<meta property="article:publisher" content="https://facebook.com/tnilivepage/" />
<meta property="article:tag" content="chaganti pravachanam" />
<meta property="article:tag" content="nagpur andhra association" />
<meta property="article:section" content="Devotional" />
<meta property="article:published_time" content="2019-04-29T15:42:05+00:00" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://i.imgur.com/yI2Kwob.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://i.imgur.com/yI2Kwob.jpg" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Chaganti Pravachanam On Venkateswara Vaibhavam In Nagpur - Latest Devotional Breaking News In Telugu | నాగ్‌పూర్ ప్రవాసులను పరవశింపజేసిన చాగంటి ప్రవచనం" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Chaganti Pravachanam On Venkateswara Vaibhavam In Nagpur" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@tnilive_editor" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://i0.wp.com/i.imgur.com/1TDYQNc.jpg?ssl=1" />
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@tnilive_editor" />
```

Here is another metadata set generated after this section and some other data

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Chaganti Pravachanam On Venkateswara Vaibhavam In Nagpur" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Chaganti Pravachanam On Venkateswara Vaibhavam In Nagpur">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://i.imgur.com/1TDYQNc.jpg" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Chaganti Pravachanam On Venkateswara Vaibhavam In Nagpur" /> />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Chaganti Pravachanam On Venkateswara Vaibhavam In Nagpur" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://i.imgur.com/1TDYQNc.jpg" />
```

If you observe closely, you can see that the og:image of Yoast SEO is different from that of the theme/unknown plugin/jetpack generated one in the second set. This is because Yoast only generates og:image tag when there is an image in the post content. And when there is just plain text even with featured image set, it doesn't put one. More info in this issue here - https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/issues/12794

Now all I want is to add some sort of a code into my functions.php file to make the second set of metadata go away except for og:image tag. Here is the expected result

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://i.imgur.com/1TDYQNc.jpg" />
```

This way I can make sure that my Yoast SEO's metadata is retained and the og:image tag issue is also fixed.

I spoke to the theme developer and they mention that other than the title tag and description tag, their theme is not generating any opengraph tags as the one in the second set. I highly doubt Jetpack and any ideas are most welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Easy: disable all plugins, except for Yoast. If the duplicate OG metatags disappear from your `<head>` section then it's a plugin that's causing the issue. Enable them one by one until the problem reappears and you'll have your culprit.

Comment: Good idea. But our theme design is based on siteorigin. We can't disable all of the plugins. If we do so, it is going to crash our site. And once I disable these, should I have to post a new article or if I just refresh my already published posts, will it generate a new head? Thanks.

Comment: Clone your site locally (or create a staging site) and do the test there. Testing on live sites is usually not a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

if you have Yoast SEO, you can disable the duplicate open graph generation from Avada -> options -> advanced -> you'll find an option to disable open graph.

Hope this will help.